# How can I install a list of timezones in a yocto-base Linux distribution?

Tags: timezone, yocto, systemd

In my Yocto distribution is installed the `systemd-timesyncd` service and the program `timedatectl`.
I have configured a UTC NTP Server in the file `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`. The `systemd-timesyncd` service works correctly and synchronizes date and time with the NTP server and so my system time is synchronized with the Universal Time (UTC).

I need to set my **timezone** and I know that I can use the command: `timedatectl set-timezone <timezone>`.
When I execute: `timedatectl list-timezones` to get the list of all timezones available the output of the command is:

```
> timedatectl list-timezones
UTC
```

I don't find any file `/usr/share/zoneinfo` or `/usr/zoneinfo`.

I think I miss installing something in my distribution but I don't know what..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a list of available timezones to a Linux distribution base on yocto it is necessary to add following assignament:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " tzdata"
```

This installs the package `tzdata` and after this the execution of  the command `timedatectl list-timezones` outpus all timezones available.

One possible path for info about timezones is `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.